# TYPO3 - Render usergroups of a logged in user as a comma separated string in fluid

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

How can I render the usergroups of a logged in user as a comma separated string in fluid? So I would like to the this:

```
3,9
```

Controller:

```
$user = $this->userRepository->findByUid($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid']);
$this->view->assign('user', $user);
```

List.html

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main"> 

    <f:debug>{user}</f:debug>   

</f:section>
```

Extbase Variable Dump

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser prototype persistent entity (uid=4, pid=25)
   username => protected 'testuser01' (10 chars)
   password => protected 'sdfgsdxxcxsdf' (34 chars)
   usergroup => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage prototype object (2 items)
      00000000sdffsa => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup prototype persistent entity (uid=3, pid=25)
         title => protected 'Group 1' (7 chars)
         uid => protected 3 (integer)
         ...
      0000000werwerw => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup prototype persistent entity (uid=9, pid=25)
         title => protected 'Group 2' (7 chars)
         ...
         uid => protected 9 (integer)
         ...
   name => protected 'Test User 01' (12 chars)
   firstName => protected 'Test' (4 chars)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `f:for` viewhelper like below.

```
<f:for each="{user.usergroup}" as="group" iteration="iterator">
    {group.uid}
    <f:if condition="{iterator.isLast}">
        <f:then> </f:then>
        <f:else>,</f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<f:for each="{user.usergroup}" as="usergroupItem" iteration="iterator">
    {usergroupItem.uid}
    <f:if condition="{iterator.isLast}">
        <f:else>, </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```